# Downcast generic to object

Tags: c#, generics

I am writing this generic method, which checks if a row already exists in a db.
My problem is the downcasting from generic to specific object.

```
private bool exists<T>(APIModel am) where T : new()
{
    var table = SelectAll<T> ();
    foreach(var r in table)
    {
        APIModel conv = (APIModel)r; //Problem
    }
    return false;
}
```

A lot of objects inherit from `APIModel`.

Here is how I use this `if(exists<Channel>(currentChannel)) ...`

Comment: What is the type of `table`? Why does this method has to be generic if you are going to cast it to `APIModel` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the relation between `T` and `APIModel` in your method definition.

Try this:

```
private bool exists<T>(T am) where T : APIMode,new()
{
    var table = SelectAll<T> ();
    foreach(var r in table)
    {
        APIModel conv = (APIModel)r; //Problem
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: BTW, if T is at least APIMode, why do you still need a cast?

Comment: This should help with the compilation problem, I'm not sure about the rest of the methodology of your exists check though.

Comment: If `T` is APIMode, you don't need a cast

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Good point, although in that case the entire conversion line of code dissappears as the OP can work directly with `r`.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer True. I removed the casting.